# Hesk 3 Support Platform CSS Customization

Tags: html, css

So i am looking forward to customize the hesk3 Support page, changing the theme to a darker color with red accents, but i can't figure out how the custom CSS and everything works.

I've tried to add the style and everything, but i wasn't able to figure it out.

I am looking forward on how to learn to customize it as adding a  tag within the given txt file was not working, or i was setting it properly.

As said, the platform has 3 default customization options, footer, header and body txt files that are supposed to have the custom code that you're looking to include.

I am looking forward to add a logo to the header and as said before, change to a dark theme with red accents.

Trying to css change the body color is not working, and none of the options i've tried were not working.

From how much i've seen withing the code, the elements of the page are definied as default, no extra subelements were set.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the background-color of the body in the chrome dev tool, try adding `!important` after each property.

```css
body { 
  background-color: red!important;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .95)!important;
}
```

If this doesnt work check if your files are imported properly

Comment: Not sure if i'm doing anything wrong, or if it's as you've said something has not been imported properly, but whatever i add, it ends up as a raw textline on the page, such as an <p> element.

Comment: @ZetaReactor, well then I guess you are using the wrong file format. I can't really diagnose anything without seeing your project, if it's important to you, here you can hit me up on Discord **Simplicius#9705**